# Structuremap 2.0 documentation

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'm just starting to learn DI/IOC methods and like what I see so far from Structuremap.  The problem is that my current project is limited to .NET 2.0 so I cannot use the new version (2.5) of Structuremap.  That being said, can someone point me towards some documentation for v2.0?  Most articles and tutorials use v2.5 and only a small few use previous versions.  The ones I can find are VERY basic in nature and I'd like to see all the features Structuremap has to offer.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to download the Docs folder from the `Release_2.0` tag of StructureMap's subversion repository:

http://structuremap.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/structuremap/tags/Release_2.0/Docs/

If you do not have subversion installed, there is a link at the bottom to download a GNU tarball, which you should be able to open with 7zip.